# Does $\int^3_0 (9-x^2)^{-3/2}\, dx$ converge?

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

> Does $$\int^3_0 {dx \over (9-x^2)^{3 \over 2}}$$ converge?

I tried to compare to $1 \over x^3$ and $1 \over x^{3 \over 2}$ using *compare test* and *limit compare test* but it didn't work out.
(I don't want to calculate directly $lim_{\epsilon \to 3^+}\int^{3- \epsilon}_0 {dx \over (9-x^2)^{3 \over 2}}$ and to see if this limit exists or not)

Comment: Start by substituting $u=3-x$ to get $\int_0^3 (u(u+6))^{-3/2}\,du$, which you can then compare to $1/u$.

Comment: Guess: Substituting $x=3\sin x$ will work as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $9-x^2=(3+x)(3-x) $. So your integral is comparable to
$$
\int_0^3\frac1 {(3-x)^{3/2}}\,dx.
$$